# Integrating web login page and duo device management client library

Tags: python, node.js, apache

Can someone give me pointers for baking in Duo device management portal (DMP) libraries to a web page?

I have a working ldap authenticated (blank) web page served via httpd (Apache) on a Linux system.
Users are to be able to provide their ldap credentials to access this page and then we need to be able to present users with DMP page.

Duo libraries are available for python, java, php, node.js etc.
(EG. https://github.com/duosecurity/duo_python, or
https://github.com/duosecurity/duo_php, or https://github.com/duosecurity/duo_nodejs)

How would I include such library code to be served via httpd?
Any links or documentation I should be referring to for getting started?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using PHP. With that I am using ldap_bind to check if the user entering credentials can be authenticated. Ldap_bind samples are abound here on stackoverflow.
Then one can use demo php code provided by DUO to call DMP api host as long as above LDAP authentication was successful.